# CodeIgniter models and properties

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question relating to properties for a specific instance of a CI model. For example:

There is a model called project_model. In the model it has a method calle Get_Projects:

```
$total_projects = $this->project_model->Get_Projects($options);
```

When this is called it creates a property in the model like so:

```
$query = $this->db->get('projects');//query

$this->num_rows = $query->num_rows();

return $query->result();
```

So after the method has been called and in the controller, I need to access num_rows:

```
$num_rows = $total_projects->num_rows;
```

(I know some of you may question the reason behind using num rows in the controller. It's to do with setting the pagination. There may be better ways of doing it but there is no time in this particular project.)

My problem is that this creates a syntax error:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/projects.php
Line Number: 110 ($num_rows = $total_projects->num_rows;)
```

Firstly why is this? I was thinking of using this: $this->project_model::num_rows instead? But then the num_rows won't be specific to the $total_rows object will it? So it will just be for the entire model.

BTW: I read the CI guide on models but there wasn't any information on creating instances of models at all.

EDITED: I need the result of num_rows property to be object-specific. So for example:

```
$a=$this->project_model->Get_Projects($options);
$b=$this->project_model->Get_Projects($options);
$num_rows = $this->project_model->num_rows;
```

The final line will get the result of $b num_rows and not $a. So How do I call it so that I can make it object-specific? (Obviously I could store it before the second call in a variable.)

Comment: I actually think I've been going about this the wrong way because a class-property will only ever store a single value in CI. I think I need to send back the num_rows with the result(). So I'm playing with that code now. Currently I have this: $query = $this->db->get("projects"); $result->result = $query->result(); $result->num_rows = $query->num_rows(); (It's hard to do this in comments with no newlines.) Basically I'm just creating a property for result and a property for num_rows. But how do I declare $result prior to using it? Do I need to use var? Confused at the moment.

Comment: I'm also going to use list() on the controller side so that I can get back the result and num rows separately and create variables with them.

Comment: I solved my own problem. I will post the solution tomorrow. I'm not allowed because I don't have 100 exp or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just instantiate a the model each time you need it.

```
$object_one = new $this->project_model;
$foo = $object_one->Get_Projects($options);
var_dump($foo);
echo $object_one->num_rows;

$object_two = new $this->project_model;
$bar = $object_two->Get_Projects($options);
var_dump($bar);
echo $object_two->num_rows;
```

This way you can get/set any attributes of each model instance seperatly.

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to do instances. Why is this not in the docs!?

Comment: It is kinda basic OOP, I have never seen it in the docs mind you. CI itself is just one huge object (do a var_dump($this) and watch your browser hang)

Comment: I just never new the syntax for doing it. $object_one = new $this->project_model; seems weird. When I learnt Java it would be like: Project object_one = new Project(); for example.

Comment: True, leaving the function call part out is a CI quirk

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your variable `$total_projects` doesn't have an instance of the class. It just contains the results from the `Get_Projects()` function.

You should try, after doing everything, `$num_rows = $this->project_model->num_rows` (untested)

Comment: But that isn't an instance is it? It's just $this->project_model->num_rows, no mention of total_rows. So if I make 2 calls to the Get_Projects method then the result of $this->project_model->num_rows will change with each call. I want to be able to get back the individual num_rows property for each call.

Comment: @Adamantus its better you add this requirement in your question.

Comment: Shiplu: I addded the part about being object-specific to the original question as you asked.

Comment: @Adamantus, you can, instead of returning `$query->result()`, return `$query`, then `$a = $this->project_model->Get_Projects($options);` and `$a->results()` and `$a->num_rows()` should be available to you.

Comment: Indrnil: I'm trying to stay as true as possible to MVC whilst at the same time having num_rows available to me. This question was provoked because I was originally using that two-line option. I was sending back get() and then using it but I wanted a one-line option to improve my code for future projects. Look in my comments at top for what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to make two queries.

One for the num rows and other for the result.

You are returning the result only, not the num rows. So it won't return the value.

Make each query in different function. And then call from that function.

I am not sure about performance side though.

Comment: Yes, I just added a comment to the OP to talk about this option.

Answer (score 0):

```
****** Model ****

class Project_model extends .... {

    private $num_rows = 0;
    public function Get_Projects($options){
        .....
        $query = $this->db->get('projects');//query
        $this->num_rows = $query->num_rows();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public get_num_rows(){
        return $this->num_rows;
    }
}

**** Controller ****

class Project extends .... {
    function project(){
        ...
        $total_projects = $this->project_model->Get_Projects($options);
        $num_rows = $this->project_model->get_num_rows();
        ...
    }
}
```

Not a perfect exaple of encapsulation but....